# How to "prefix" order by expression using dynamic-linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq

So I have this scenario where I need to "by pass" the `OrderBy` expression into a nested property but I can't simply change the expression because it's used in too many places without concerning the nested property.

For example, I have these two classes that are used to generate an `IQueryable<Parent>` and the order is applied using `.OrderBy("Title DESC")` and so on. However, the `"Title DESC"` expression is provided by the outside world, which makes it very hard to refactor.

```
class Parent {
  public Nested NestedProp {get;set;}
  /* other irrelevant props */
}

class Nested {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public DateTime CreatedAt {get;set;}
  /* other irrelevant props */
}
```

And I recover it through a method like this:

```
public IQueryable<Parent> GetParentsOrdered(stirng order){
    IQueryable<Parent> query = QueryParents();
    
    return query.OrderBy(order);
}
```

And usage goes like this:

```
var listOfParents = GetParentsOrdered("Title DESC");
```

The problem is, in order to make it work properly, I have to take into account the `NestedProp` on the order by expression, which would require too much refactor in a source that I don't fully control, just to get the ordering to work immediately.

Example:

```
var listOfParents = GetParentsOrdered("Nested.Title DESC");
```

The question is, is there any means to tell Dynamic Linq to prefix the expression with `NestedProp` so that I can do the ordering by simply providing the child's property directly on the expression and by pass the ordering directly to `NestedProp`?

Something like this:

```
query.OrderByPrefixed("NestedProp", "Title DESC, CreatedAt DESC");
```

Comment: No, you need to specify the prefix on every property. You could do that with some string manipulation though, but it's fragile. What if you want to order by a parent property and then a nested property? Why can't you get the caller to pass in the proper string? Or even better, don't use dynamic Linq and pass in a proper `Expression`.

Comment: Thank you @DavidG, I appreciate your input. To give you more off-topic details on the subject, someone abused the fact that it's easy to use dynamic linq expressions and allowed the client [js, angular, react] to provide ordering expressions for data tables. The problem is, they didn't take into account the nested property, meaning none of the ordering works because of that. I'm trying to find alternative ways to allow this ordering to work at least temporarily without having to refactor the clients that consume it.

Comment: This is exactly why you should use statically typed queries rather than dynamically typed queries when the schema and the nature of the query itself doesn't require it being dynamic.

Comment: Well, dynamic queries are precisely good for that, the problem is they didn't implement it properly so now I have to intercept the usage and fix it to make the system work :/

Comment: So the client strings are being passed directly into the dynamic Linq commands? Eek, that's pretty dangerous and I would rewrite that immediatley.

Comment: As long as `Parent` and `Nested` didn't share property names, you could use Reflection and `Regex.Replace` to modify the string for all `Nested` property names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code using Reflection to automatically prefix nested property names. An expansion could be done to automatically extract (multiple) nested properties. This code assumes there is no overlap in property names between `Parent` and `Nested`.

```
static List<string> NestedPropertyNames = typeof(Nested).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();
static Regex srcPattern = new Regex(@"(?<=\W|^)(?:"+String.Join("|", NestedPropertyNames)+@")(?=\W|$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public IQueryable<Parent> GetParentsOrdered(string order){
    IQueryable<Parent> query = QueryParents();

    return query.OrderBy(srcPattern.Replace(order, "NestedProp.$&"));
}
```